How to get a GPS Information with private-lte network In Flutter App.(All Google services were blocked)
I'm developing flutter application. and i have to get a GPS Value. but this app is in private-LTE network. so all of Google services are blocked. At first, i used LocationManager Class in java. but it didn't work.
so i want to get a GPS without internet. in addition, all of devices are never connect with public network.
i want to my device get a GPS
